# Can i port forward to router itself?

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding

I want to access router setup page(192.168.1.1) from internet. Can i forward port form internet to my router IP because i want to change the settings of the router from remote area. I tried it but it says ip address can not be same as routers IP.

Comment: Leaving your router open to access from the public internet is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is possible to forward a port to the LAN IP address of the router itself. The limitation you encountered seems arbitrary.

But you don't necessarily need to forward a port (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). To "change the settings of the router from remote area", a straightforward thing to do is to make the "router setup page" accessible on its WAN interface, on its WAN IP address. Technically it's something different than forwarding a port. Your router may or may not provide an option to do this.

Exposing the setup page to the Internet is a security risk. If there is no option to do this then maybe it's this way deliberately to protect you. If you managed to forward a port to reach the setup page then it would be equally (in)secure.

If the router can be accessed via SSH, consider exposing the SSH service instead (preferably on some nonstandard port). I expect it to be more secure than the router setup page itself. Then you will be able to reach the setup page by logging in via SSH and forwarding a local port this way (e.g. `ssh -p port -NL 8088:192.168.1.1:80 user@WAN_IP`, then `localhost:8088` in a browser).

This answer is very generic because you revealed nothing about your router.